# Stop Mediaplayer Automatically

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Is there a way where i can stop the MediaPlayer automatically after 20 seconds?
Does the function `seekTo(20)` works?

Comment: I don't know how to use seekTo() but you can also use thread for doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [seekTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29)(20) it will skip the song to 20 miliseconds, so that's not what you need.

You can use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) for this:

> public final boolean **postDelayed** (Runnable r, long delayMillis)
>
> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be **run after the specified amount of time elapses**. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

First you create a new Handler, than you call *postDelayed()* to execute a new Runnable object. If you want to use it to pause a mediaplayer, here's a little example for you:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}, 20000);
```